# filtering multiple items by data-cat

Tags: jquery, html

I have this script that was filtering my products very well. But now, I have some products that are part of two different categories, and i must list them on both. What i need to implement?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var Portfolio = {
            sort: function(items) {
                items.show();
                $('#produtos-content').find('div.portfolio-item').not(items).fadeOut(500);
            },
            showAll: function(items) {
                items.fadeIn(500);
            },
            doSort: function() {
                $('a', '#produtos-sort').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $a = $(this);
                    if (!$a.is('#all')) {
                        var items = $('div[data-cat=' + $a.data('cat') + ']', '#produtos-content');
                        Portfolio.sort(items);
                    } else {
                        Portfolio.showAll($('div.portfolio-item', '#produtos-content'));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        Portfolio.doSort();     
    });
</script>
```

my HTML:

Sortable Buttons:

```
<div id="produtos-sort">
    <a href="#" id="all">ALL</a>
    <a href="#" data-cat="cat_1">TABLET</a>
    <a href="#" data-cat="cat_2">CELLPHONES</a>
    <a href="#" data-cat="cat_1 cat_2">ANDROID</a>
</div>
```

And the Display:

```
<div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="cat_1">
    <a href="produtos/grande/big_image.jpg" title="TABLET" class="lightbox" rel="cat_1">
        <img src="produtos/pequena/small_image.jpg"  />
    </a>
    <div class="produto_ref">
        <p>TABLET</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="cat_1 cat_2">
    <a href="produtos/grande/big_image.jpg" title="ANDROID" class="lightbox" rel="cat_1">
        <img src="produtos/pequena/small_image.jpg"  />
    </a>
    <div class="produto_ref">
        <p>ANDROID</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't get what you really want

Comment: Using my example... look at my Sortable Buttons... if i click on Tablet (cat_1) this must display all itens that have cat_1 on the Display option, so.. This must show the "ANDROID" and "TABLET" ok?, If i click on CELLPHONES (cat_2) this must show only the ANDROID option... this dont works with my script at this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code-

```
$("#produtos-sort a").click(function(){
   var dc = $(this).attr('data-cat');
    if(dc=="all") {
      $('.portfolio-item').show();
       return;
     }
    $('.portfolio-item').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('data-cat').indexOf(dc) < 0) $(this).hide(); else $(this).show();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Ok.. this works.. but, on my code i have the option to show ALL, ii have some button with `id="all"` how can i implement on your code?

Comment: ya let me just make the change